# Android: how do I fix timestamp addition to my SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a TIMESTAMP Column to my SQLite database.  The column is to be used to capture timestamp data using "System.currentTimeMillis();".  App is crashing and the error is from the cursor code shown below in the line with ** **.  The error reads "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...ListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 6 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Initially I set up the variable as a String in the model file.  Then I tried  a long and neither worked.  What am I missing here?

UserData file:

```
...
public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
```

DatabaseHelper.java file:

```
...
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID +
                  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TODO +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE1 +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE2 +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DUEDATE +
                  " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DUETIME +
                " TEXT,"
                + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP +
                  " TEXT" + ")";
...

public void insertIntoDB(String todo, String note1, String note2, String duedate, String duetime, long timestamp) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TODO, todo);
    values.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE1, note1);
    values.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE2, note2);
    values.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DUEDATE, duedate);
    values.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DUETIME, duetime);        
    values.put(DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);

    db.insert(DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
...

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    UserData userData = new UserData();
                    userData.setTodo(cursor.getString(1));
                    userData.setNote1(cursor.getString(2));
                    userData.setNote2(cursor.getString(3));
                    userData.setDuedate(cursor.getString(4));
                    userData.setDuetime(cursor.getString(5));
                    **userData.setTimestamp(cursor.getLong(6));**

                    modelList.add(0, userData);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
...
```

ListAdapter.java file:

```
...
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    holder.cardBlankText5.setText((int) dbList.get(position).getTimestamp());
```

Activity.java file:

```
...
public void onClickSave(View v) {
    ...
    long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(Activity.this);
    helper.insertIntoDB(todo,note1,note2,duedate,duetime,timestamp);
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this,ListActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: after `rawQuery` call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`, what do you see?

Comment: @CL Do you mean call dumpCursor and show the Logcat result?

Comment: @pskink  after running dumpCursor this is what was shown: "E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 6 from a CursorWindow which has 33 rows, 6 columns."

Comment: I am wondering if I should be deleting the existing database since it previously only had 5 data columns (plus the _ID) column) and already had data and starting with a new database with no data, please advise.

Comment: what is query passed to rawQuery method?

Comment: String query = "select * from "+DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME;

Comment: CL's link above to was very helpful to resolve my issues.  Specifically see "laalto's" answer at url:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run.

Answer (score -1):

Having `DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP` as a `DATETIME` type should work. I usually have utility method that takes the cursor and column name and returns a Date object:

```
public static Date getDateColumn(Cursor c, String column) {
    Date d = null;
    Long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column));
    if (time != null && time != 0) {
         d = new Date();
         d.setTime(time);
    }
    return d;
}
```

The second thing to check is whether or not that field is being asked for in your query. Sharing the value of `query` could shed some light, but usually you get things like this when the column you are asking for isn't in the projection.

e.g. select columnA, columnB from mytable; and then you try to get something from columnC which isn't in the results.

Comment: Right so I am trying to do the query on the database and setting the timestamp data in the Cursor so I can use the Cursor in a RecyclerView list.  Not sure how I would use your utility method with my userData object for the cursor as shown above.

Comment: Only line 3 is pertinent for you as you wish to store it as a long in your POJO, if you want to store it as a Date object then the method is useful. In any case, storing as `DATETIME` in the table should resolve your issue. Make sure you remove your app and reinstall it after changing the table definition though.

Comment: So you are recommending replacing the "TEXT" for TIMESTAMP with "DATETIME"?

Comment: Yep, then Uninstall the app like @Sergey Chechenev mentioned. Hold down the app icon and drag up to the top and dump in Uninstall. Then run the app again from Android Studio.

Comment: Ok did that with device (phone).  App still crashing.

Comment: Can you debug and post the value of `query` that you pass into `db.rawQuery(query, null)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110456/discussion-between-rossco-and-ajw).

Comment: Haven't done debug as I'm an android newbie.  Too late here now so I will pick back up tomorrow.  I appreciate your help to try to get me up and running.

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to get Long from column declared as TEXT. Declare it as INTEGER.
Or use getString() and convert value to Long.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I will try to replace with INT.

Comment: No luck, same error being thrown.

Comment: Are you sure that database was recreated on device/emulator? Or you use db with old values?

Comment: First I cleaned and rebuilt project and then ran the app.  I can't even get to the activity which is a RecyclerView list to enter any new values.  App crashes when trying to create the list.

Comment: Remove app from device and run it again. Cleaning project does not delete app from device.

Comment: I am using emulator.  I closed the emulator and re-started a new one and same error resulted.

Comment: I believe emulator stores it's data on hard drive and reloads them after restart.

Comment: Remove app from emulator like you do on real device.

Comment: I use Android Studio to create the app.  So are you saying close the emulator and close Android Studio and then re-open both and run app again?

Comment: No, I suggest use android emulator interface to remove app from emulator's OS. Like on real device.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.  What if I just remove the app from my device (smartphone) and then re-run app on the device?

Comment: It will be the same, but on your smartphone. On emulator use Settings-Manage applications. If your emulator looks like real smartphone.

Comment: I'll try.  I am using genymotion emulator.

Comment: I cleared cache in emulator, that was the only setting available.  Still crashing with same error message.